# Как сохранить данные в таблицу через модель?

Tags: php, magento

Нужно сохранить изменение в таблице (Magento Full Release - ver 1.9.2.4) через модель:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
           ->load($id=1);

$product->setName('AU');
$product->save();
```

Но выбрасывает ошибку:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Но цикл я нигде не использую!

**Как исправить данную ошибку ?**

Comment: попробуйте установить admin стору `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);` перед сохранением.

Comment: @Naumov, да так работает ) А это не возможно обойти ?

Comment: По мойму есть метод который устанавливает права админа, но это просто дублирование установки store. Дело в том что редактировать продукт имеет право только администратор. Опишите суть задачи и я вам смогу предложить вариант решения. А пока я оформлю коментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте установить admin store перед сохранением.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка не относитя к приведённому коду.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Попробуй отловить ошибку полностью

```
try {
    // код метода с ошибкой
} catch(Exception $e) { 
    echo ($e->getMessage()."<BR><BR>".nl2br($e->getTraceAsString()); );
    die();
}
```

Comment: сделал но ничего не изменилось